# uinavigationbar moves up when returning from inactive state

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a custom image header ABOVE the uinavigationbar.  I do this with this code:

```
self.navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0); 
self.navController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 73.0, 320.0, 44.0);

UIView *checkNav = [self.navController.view viewWithTag:9999];
if (checkNav == nil) {
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header-logo.jpg"]];
    imgView.tag = 9999;
    [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 23.0, 320.0, 50.0)];
    [self.navController.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

This works great.  But, when the app goes inactive (hit the main iphone home button) and then you go back into the app, the uinavigationbar shifts up to the default place at the top of the screen and is hidden behind my custom header image.

I've tried throwing code into applicationDidBecomeActive, but it doesn't help.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the code you "threw" into applicationDidBecomeActive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do get warned about this in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationController):

> With only a few exceptions, you should never modify the navigation bar object directly. It is permissible to modify the barStyle or translucent properties of the navigation bar but **you must never change its frame, bounds, or alpha values directly**

Having said that, you should be able to get the effect by repeating your above code in applicationDidBecomeActive or applicationWillEnterForeground, assuming you have a pointer to the navigation controller from there. You may find that hiding and re-showing the navigation bar is required (bit of a hack, but it can help - I had a similar problem with hiding / showing the status bar and the navigation bar not going to its correct place)

Comment: Ah!  I missed that in the docs ... thanks for pointing that out.  I can't chance the app getting denied because of the navbar.  So, I will be changing the design around to put the navigationbar back where it should go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about putting the code into viewWillAppear?

Comment: That doesn't work for when it first "wakes up" (just tried again to make sure), but once the app is back and I navigate to the view that I have it set with viewWillAppear ... it corrects itself.  Just not on load.  If that makes sense.  =)

Comment: A bit stumped too, does it have to be a navbar could you use a toolbar instead?